# How to get kubernetes service name instead of 'traefik' pod's IP

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

It is hard to check if request is reached the service or not, because we get  RouterName like `namespace-ingressroute_name-some_random_string@kubernatescrd` and ServiceName like
`namespace-ingressroute_name-some_random_string` instead of pod service name.

Is there any way I can print pod service name instead of that RouterName and ServiceName in logs?

Comment: Could you elaborate on topic? Where you get that RouterName/ServiceName and how you are searching for it?  Do you search in logs or with CLI tools?  Could you provide exact output maybe? At the moment it is not clear what is the question.

Comment: i found a solution for that we can use traefik service for that. which is introduce in traefik version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for that we can use traefik service for that. which is introduce in traefik version 2.0